# Spring - Instanciate a bean with a class which throws an Exception

Tags: spring

I'm trying to instanciate a bean which constructor could throw an Exception.
I can't modify this class (given by an external team).

```
<bean id="myClass" class="myClass" />
```

The myClass constructor throws Exception.

I've been thinking about extending this class with a Singleton Pattern which is the behavior I want (be sure to instantiate only one instance of MyClass).

Error message :

> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'myClass'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [.../spring_applicationContext.xml]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [myClass]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Thanks in advance for your answers

I think the problem comes from the fact that my constructor throws an Exception.

**My question is : with Spring, is it possible to instanciate a bean with a constructor which could throw an exception ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no bean scope is specified in bean configuration file, default to singleton. Your bean `myClass` is a singleton and you dont need to do anything more.
[Spring Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that Spring manage the Singleton by default. But if I try to use Spring, I have an Exception when it tries to load the context (because the constructor of myClass throws Exception)

Comment: @Galephico: As Anders mentioned adding complete stacktrace can help to identify the problem.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that my constructor throws an Exception. My question is : with Spring, is it possible to instanciate a bean with a constructor which could throw Exception ?

Comment: @Galephico: If constructor is throwing an exception what you expect from Spring? Spring is not enough smart to deal with exception and still create bean. Also the exception is thrown from a static block so there you need to check with external team/documentaion.

Comment: I thought the Spring error was due to the fact that myClass **could** throw an Exception, not the fact that it did throw an Exception while Spring tried to instancied the beam.
As I hadn't any error when doing MyClass myClass = new MyClass().
Thanks for your different answers to you and @Anders Rostgaard Bystrup

Answer (score 1):

Spring beans are by default singletons.

You should provide more of the stacktrace - what you're showing indicates that it is not myClass that is the problem, but the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` constructor that throws an exception - the cause usually follows later in the stacktrace.

Cheers,

Comment: If the `myClass` constructor really throws the exception you're out of luck anyways - you need to figure out why it does so and fix that!

Comment: It throws an Exception because it access properties and I can't modify myClass, unfortunately. That's why I thought about the Singleton Pattern to instanciate myClass

Comment: OK, if the constructor throws an exception then the object is not constructed and consequently of no use to you! If you by "...access properties..." mean that the constructor expects a properties file somewhere you should provide that on the class path! Bottomline: You have to solve the exception situation, otherwise you won't get anywhere!

Comment: Incidentally an `ExceptionInInitializerError` is usually caused by an exception in a `static` context (initalizer/variable) - you could decompile the class and get an idea of the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

As per stack trace, looks like there is an unexpected error either in static block or variable while creating an object of class 'myClass'.